# Python script TypeError

Tags: python, api

Здравствуйте!
В моем скрипте появляется ошибка, никак не пойму почему?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import requests
import json
import logging
ip = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
user = 'z'
password = '4321'
login_url = 'https://' + ip + "/restapi/16/authenticate"
login_data = 'data={"username":"' + user + '","password":"'
login_data = login_data + password + '"}'
login_headers = {'Accept':'application/json'}
r = requests.post(login_url, login_data, verify=False, headers=login_headers)
data = r.json()
for item in data:
 if item["status"]!='1':
  continue
 else:
  break
 print('Ok')
```

Появляется такая ошибка:

```
if item["status"]=='1':
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Где ошибка?

Comment: Вы и строчку с ошибкой привели, и даже сообщение говорит о причине. Вы пытаетесь использовать строку как индекс в списке, питон так не умеет.

Comment: Расскажите ход ваших мыслей, почему вы решили, что в переменной `item` лежит такой объект, у которого можно достать некий `status`?

Comment: Еще расскажите какого вида json вы ожидаете от сервера? Вероятно пришло не то, что вы ожидаете, вероятно авторизация вообще не была успешной. Попробуйте выполнить `r.rise_for_status()` сразу после запроса.

Comment: Запрос успешно выполняется, после запроса он выдает несколько атрибутов, один из которых статус. Вот я и хочу сделать проверку статуса после запроса, типо если статус 1, то продолжить, а если что-то другое то сломаться и выдать сообщение.

Comment: Приложите json, быстрее поможем решим проблему.

Answer (score 0):

И того добрый день.

1. Почему Вы решили что в ответ придет json.
2. Почему Вы решили что item есть такой элемент словаря?

Из это вытекает:

1. Чекайте статус

requests.status_code == requests.codes.ok

2. Чекайте есть ли в словаре "status", может там "errorStatus"

item.get("status") == None

ЗЫ. Еще str.format str.join

```
data={"username":user,"password":password}
```

Но если Вам хочется и сил нет

```
login_data = "data={"username":{a},"password":{b}}".format(a=str(user),b=str(password))

login_url = str.join("",("https://",ip,"/restapi/16/authenticate"))
```